# Does streaming video pass through the website's server when embedded with javascript from another site?

Tags: javascript, web-development, internet

Not sure how else to phrase this question, so my apologies if it's been asked before.

We use Brightcove for streaming video. They offer an option to embed one of their players on your webpage using Javascript embed code.

From a high-level standpoint, when the a user types in the URL of our webpage, that call hits our server, which sends the page back to the user's browser to render. If the page has the Brightcove embed Javascript on it, which happens?...

1. Javascript request goes to our web server, our web server goes to Brightcove's servers for the video stream, Brightcove's servers send the video stream to us, and we send it down to the user's browser.  OR...
2. Javascript request goes to Brightcove's servers for the stream, and Brightcove's servers send the video stream back to the user's browser (no video bandwidth needed from our web server).

We're assuming the latter is true, but we want to double check?

Comment: Have you considered using tools like the browser's built in developer tools, Fiddler, or Wireshark to examine the traffic?  Honestly, that's the ***best*** way to figure out what calls are being made to where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is JavaScript. Your server's not involved that much. If the embedding is done in pure JavaScript without calls you your server, then the video should go straight to the User's browser.